# Not appending characters to parent window's textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    new nicEditor({fullPanel : true},{buttonList : ['fontSize','bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough','subscript','superscript','html','image']}).panelInstance('area2');
    });
    //]]>
    function popup_specialChars()
    {
        var ht;
        if(window.navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 5.01") == -1)
            ht = 330;
        else
            ht = 720;
        specialCharsWindow = window.open
        (
            "specialChars.php", "special_characters",
            "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=" + ht + ",width=650,dependent=yes,alwaysRaised=yes"
        );
        specialCharsWindow.focus();
    }
    </script>


      <a href="javascript:popup_specialChars();" class="special">Insert Special Character</a>


       <textarea  id="area1" name="txttitle" style="height: 150;width: 600"></textarea>
```

**specialChars.php**

here I have a javascript function

```
function insert_text(str)
{
    alert(str);
    window.opener.document.getElementById('area1').value += str;
    this.window.focus();
}
```

Now question is, i am getting character in alert, but it is not appending to parent window's textarea. Why this happens ?

Comment: Text Areas do not store the text in value! It is the child text. Use jQuery's `.val()` method as it will automatically compensate for the type of control.